# SwiftUI Filtering/Searching a Two Level Data Model

Tags: swift, search, multidimensional-array, data-structures, uisearchbar

I am trying to use a search bar to search/filter through a two-level data model in SwiftUI:

```
struct CategorySection: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var image: String
    var color: Color
    var paintings: [Painting]
}

struct Painting {
    var title: String
    var size: String
    var year: String
    var text: String
    var show: Bool
} 

let categorySectionData: [CategorySection] = [
    CategorySection(title: "Flowers",
                    image: "Spring",
                    color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039269, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.6431372762, alpha: 1)),
                    paintings: [
                        Painting(title: "Spring", size: "70 x 60cm", year: "2001", text: "Spring", show: false),
                        Painting(title: "Flowers", size: "60 x 50cm", year: "2002", text: "The", show: false),
                        Painting(title: "Corn Poppys", size: "70 x 50cm", year: "2005", text: "Year", show: false),
        ]
    ),
    CategorySection(title: "Animals",
                    image: "Deers",
                    color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, green: 0.4862745106, blue: 0.1411764771, alpha: 1)),
                    paintings: [
                        Painting(title: "Tigers", size: "70 x 60cm", year: "2001", text: "Spring", show: false),
                        Painting(title: "Deers", size: "60 x 50cm", year: "2002", text: "The", show: false),
                        Painting(title: "Puppies", size: "70 x 50cm", year: "2005", text: "Year", show: false),
        ]
    )
]
```

The main objective is to filter elements, such as `title: "Spring"` and `year: "2001"` in the `Painting` struct inside `CategorySection`, display matched results in the form of paintings `title`s in the list, and pass data through `NavigationLink` for the next view `SearchDetail` to display when the user taps on one of them.

I have attempted the following to search the first elements but Xcode just gave me a bunch of error.

```
let array = locationSectionData[0].paintings[0]
```

```
List {
   ForEach(array.filter {$0.hasPrefix(searchText) || searchText == ""}, id:\.self) { searchText in
       NavigationLink(destination: SearchDetail(item: searchText)) {
           Text(searchText)
       }
   }
}
```

The above solution, however, works for simple arrays like this:

```
let array = ["Spring", "Deer", "New Year", "Flowers"]
```

but not for multi-level data structures.

Ideally, the search result should return entire instances of `Painting` struct such as

```
Painting(title: "Spring", size: "70 x 60cm", year: "2001", text: "Spring", show: false)
```

, instead of only single elements that match, if any element inside it matches the search bar input.

If anyone has ideas of how I can solve this problem that'd be great! At this point, I am not even sure it is possible given the current data structure. Modifications of the data structure are acceptable.

Thanks!

**Edited:**
I have managed to display a complete list of paintings titles without the filter function, thanks to the help from @jtouzy

```
List {
    ForEach(categorySectionData) { section in
        Section(header: Text(section.title)) {
            ForEach(section.paintings.indices, id: \.self) { painting in
                ForEach(section.paintings[painting].title.filter {$0.contains(searchText) || searchText.isEmpty}, id:\.self) { searchText in
                    NavigationLink(destination: SearchDetail(painting: section.paintings[painting])) {
                                        Text(section.paintings[painting].title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, Xcode says error `Value of type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') has no member 'contains'` on line `ForEach(section.paintings[painting].title.filter {$0.contains(searchText) || searchText.isEmpty}, id:\.self) { searchText in`. I know it is probably becuase now it is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For your answer**,

Your `ForEach` function is not based on a string but on a `Painting` object.

So you can't use `hasPrefix()` function on your array items.

Instead, access your item **title** in the `filter` function :

```
$0.title.hasPrefix(searchText)
```

You should iterate over your categories and then after on your paintings, something like this (not launched) :

```swift
List {
    ForEach(categorySectionData) { section in
        Section(header: Text(section.title)) {
            ForEach(section.paintings) { painting in // Here with your filter
               NavigationLink(destination: SearchDetail(item: painting)) {
                  Text(painting.title)
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In other hands,**

I suggest you to use `contains(where:)` instead of `hasPrefix()`, to give the availability to search in all the words.

And to be more clean in your code, use `searchText.isEmpty` instead of `searchText == ""`.

**EDIT** For the edited question, see my response in comments below.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you be more specific? I changed ForEach function to ForEach(array.filter {$0.title.contains(searchText) || searchText == ""}, and it says error "Value of type 'Painting2' has no member 'filter'".

Comment: I think that's because your elements should not be selected by this way : `let array = locationSectionData[0].paintings[0]`. You should iterate over your `locationSectionData` for creating sections, and inside it, iterate to show your items. You can find an exemple of sections here : https://fuckingswiftui.com/#list. I update my post to show you the concrete example.

Comment: Thank you for the detail! I encountered an error in the filter function. I updated my question. Could you take a look?

Comment: You are making your filter on `section.paintings[painting].title`. That means you are filtering all the characters on the string "title" (String is Iterable). You want to filter your paintings, so the filter method has to be called on `section.paintings`, and then you test `$0.title.contains()`. Do you see the point ?