# Filtering data into a list with sections

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have data sorted by priority. I'm trying to display that data in a list as:

```
priority 1
   item with that priority
   item with that priority 
priority 2
   item with that priority
   item with that priority
```

So I thought using a `list` with `sections` to display the priority, and then list under each item that has that priority.

```
struct PriorityView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var taskdata: DataModel
    @State var byPriotity: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                // priority 3 is display all items in the list
                if byPriotity == 3 {
                    ForEach(taskdata.filteredTasks(byPriority: byPriotity), id: \.id) { task in
                        Section(header: Text(getTitle(byPriority: task.priority)).font(.headline)) {
                            Text(task.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This just creates a list with a section that displays the priority, and then the title of the item. Which is not what I wanted to output.
I started reading about `section` and some articles ([this](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/swiftui-listview-part3/), [this](https://www.donnywals.com/how-to-filter-an-array-in-swift/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925025/swiftui-filtering-searching-a-two-level-data-model)) provide some good advise, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to iterate and find all items with a specific priority, create a header, and then list all those item's titles. Maybe I should add a second `forEach` filtering all of the items with that particular priority? Or save the initial filtering in a variable and then filter that? I don't know.

I tried with

```
            ForEach(taskdata.filteredTasks(byPriority: 3)) { task in
                Section(header: Text(getTitle(byPriority: task.priority)).font(.headline)) {
                    ForEach(task.priority.filter {$0.contains(byPriotity) || byPriotity.isEmpty}) {
                        Text(task.title)
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I can't filter them like that. Int doesn't have `filter`

Then I tried

`ForEach(task.priority.isEqual(to: byPriotity))`

And again, issues with an int not having `isEqual`. And I'm going in circles here...

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
struct Task: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var priority = 2
}

extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }
    
    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self), // comment all this out
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}

final class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("tasksp") public var tasks: [Task] = []
    
    init() {
        self.tasks = self.tasks.sorted(by: {
            $0.priority < $1.priority
        })
    }
    
    func sortList() {
        self.tasks = self.tasks.sorted(by: {
            $0.priority < $1.priority
        })
    }
    
    func filteredTasks(byPriority priority: Int) -> [Task] {
        tasks.filter { priority == 3 || $0.priority == priority }
    }
    
}

struct PriorityView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var taskdata: DataModel
    @State var byPriotity: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                // priority 3 is display all items in the list
                // I'm going to add another view so the user can 
                // can select what to display eventually
                if byPriotity == 3 {
                    ForEach(taskdata.filteredTasks(byPriority: byPriotity), id: \.id) { task in
                        Section(header: Text(getTitle(byPriority: task.priority)).font(.headline)) {
                            Text(task.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getTitle(byPriority:Int) -> String {
        switch byPriority {
        case 0: return "Important"
        case 1: return "Tomorrow"
        default: return "Someday"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Trying with the code that vadian suggested. I really don't know what I'm doing, but tried, and this is the result:

[image]

Changed the struct name to:

```
struct SectionOrdered : Identifiable {
    var id: String { priority }
    
    let priority: String
    let tasks: [Task]
}
```

The code I tried is:

```
List {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
        if byPriority == 3 {
            ForEach(taskdata.sections) { task in
                Section(header: task.priority) {
                    Text(task.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

vadian suggested to filter all in the class, but I have no clue how to use that. I tried, but I'm making a worse mess here.

I wonder if this is possible at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group your data into sections first create a struct `Section`

```
struct Section : Identifiable {
    var id : String { priority }
    
    let priority : String
    let tasks : [Task]
}
```

And in the view model *publish* the sections and group them in for example in the `init` method.

```
final class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("tasksp") public var tasks: [Task] = []
    
    @Published var sections = [Section]()
    
    init() {
        let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: tasks, by: \.priority)
        let sortedKeys = grouped.keys.sorted()
        self.sections = sortedKeys.map{Section(priority: getTitle(byPriority: $0), tasks: grouped[$0]!)}
    }

    func getTitle(byPriority: Int) -> String {
        switch byPriority {
            case 0: return "Important"
            case 1: return "Tomorrow"
            default: return "Someday"
        }
    }
....
```

The benefit is to keep all unnecessary data processing out of the view.

In the view show the data

```
ForEach(taskdata.sections) { section in
    Section {
        ForEach(section.tasks) { task in
            Text(task.title)
        }
    } header: {
       Text(section.priority)
          .font(.headline)
    }
}
```

If you want to group filtered data into sections first filter it then group it.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. However, how do I iterate that data and filter them by priority into sections? `ForEach (taskdata.sections)`?

Comment: As I said don't filter in the view at all. Do all the filtering in the view model and put `byPriority` (please take care of the spelling ) also into the view model. Assigning the filtered data to `sections` or whatever `@Published` property refreshes the view.

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused since now I can't use Section, but thank you. I'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the misspelling. I added some extra code after I tried, together with a screenshot above. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Once again my solution is based on doing the filter stuff in the **view model**. Remove the `if byPriority == 3 {` expression. If you want to display only one section just filter the `tasks` by `priority == 3` (in the view model!) then group it as described and assign it to `sections`. This displays only the filtered section.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Still dealing with more errors (like `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '() -> Parent'` and `Extra trailing closure passed in call` and `Generic parameter 'Parent' could not be inferred`) but I'll rewrite all from scratch.

Comment: Please see the edit for the correct section header syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much. That made it. Now to finish the rest.